# Magento : Which Event Observer Used For "Move to Shopping Cart" in Admin

Tags: admin, orders, magento-1, event-observer, shopping-cart

I want to know which event observer is used in admin while do following.

Step for better understanding (Do from admin).

1. Create a new order
2. Add a product to the order
3. Select "Move to shipping cart" in the "Action" menu
4. Click on "Update Items and "Qty's"

See this screen-sort.
[image]

Any one have idea, which event observer used when we click on **"Update Items and Qty's"** buttion after selecting **"Move to Shopping Cart"** option in action.

Comment: There are used __a lot__. It doesnt make sence to post a complete list, so what the event should be used for? (Or add logging to `Mage::dispatchEvent()` right before click the button)

Answer (score 1):

These events are triggered (some multiple times):

- resource_get_tablename
- core_collection_abstract_load_before
- core_collection_abstract_load_after
- controller_front_init_before
- controller_front_init_routers
- model_load_after
- core_abstract_load_after
- adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start
- core_locale_set_locale
- controller_action_predispatch
- model_load_before
- admin_user_load_before
- admin_user_load_after
- controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml
- core_abstract_load_before
- controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_loadBlock
- create_order_session_quote_initialized
- adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before
- sales_quote_load_before
- sales_quote_load_after
- sales_quote_address_collection_load_before
- sales_quote_address_collection_load_after
- sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes
- customer_session_init
- catalog_entity_attribute_load_after
- eav_collection_abstract_load_before
- catalog_product_collection_load_before
- catalog_product_collection_load_after
- catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_before
- prepare_catalog_product_collection_prices
- sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load
- sales_quote_item_set_product
- sales_quote_item_qty_set_after
- adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
- sales_quote_collect_totals_before
- sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before
- customer_load_before
- customer_load_after
- catalog_product_get_final_price
- customer_group_load_before
- customer_group_load_after
- tax_rate_data_fetch
- sales_quote_address_discount_item
- sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after
- sales_quote_collect_totals_after
- model_save_before
- sales_quote_save_before
- application_clean_cache
- model_save_after
- sales_quote_save_after
- sales_quote_address_save_before
- sales_quote_address_save_after
- sales_quote_item_save_before
- sales_quote_item_save_after
- model_save_commit_after
- sales_quote_address_save_commit_after
- sales_quote_item_save_commit_after
- sales_quote_save_commit_after
- controller_action_layout_load_before
- controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before
- controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before
- core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before
- core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after
- core_layout_block_create_after
- payment_method_is_active
- core_session_abstract_clear_messages
- controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after
- core_block_abstract_to_html_before
- adminhtml_block_html_before
- core_block_abstract_to_html_after
- catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after
- wishlist_item_collection_products_after_load
- sales_order_collection_load_before
- sales_order_collection_load_after
- currency_display_options_forming
- payment_form_block_to_html_before
- controller_response_redirect
- controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_loadBlock
- controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml
- controller_action_postdispatch
- controller_front_send_response_before
- http_response_send_before
- controller_front_send_response_after

<sup>(Please add what you're trying to achieve, to narrow down this list :))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the "Update Items and Qty's" button, there is a request to the `loadBlockAction()` method of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` class.

So :

1) there are the "classical" event dispatched from the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class. I think to the `controller_action_predispatch_*` and `controller_action_postdispatch_*` (Please check in the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class to get all names of events.

2) If you look in the `loadBlockAction()` method, you will that the `_processActionData()` method is called and, inside it, you will see :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before', $eventData);
```

and

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data', $eventData);
```

I guess that these two last events are more appropriate.